# Excel VBA code not pasting as date values

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code creating new column "M" and pasting date values from column "L" to it after comma delimiter. Issue is not all values are pasted as numerical dates, although they appear as such. Causing me issues further down the line where I am creating a pivot and need to sort column headers by date. Also some dates only have date as yy instead of yyyy

```
With Sheets("DataSheet")

newLastRow = pasteRowIndex

If IsArray(v) Then
    .Columns(13).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     For i = 1 To newLastRow
       If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "L"), ",") Then
        .Cells(i, "M").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "L"), ",")(1)
```

Not sure if this next line is correct

```
        Cells(i, "M").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

[image]

[image]

```
  Dim PSheet As Worksheet
  Dim DSheet As Worksheet
  Dim PCache As PivotCache
  Dim PTable As PivotTable
  Dim PRange As Range
  Dim LastRow1 As Long
  Dim LastCol As Long


  'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
  Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  'Switch off error masking
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
  Set DSheet = Worksheets("DataSheet")

  'With DSheet


  'Define Data Range
  LastRow1 = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "B").Resize(LastRow, 20)

  'Define Pivot Cache
  Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
      (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)


  'Insert Blank Pivot Table
  Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
      (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")


  'Insert Row Fields

  With PTable.PivotFields("Contract Identifier")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 1
  End With


  With PTable.PivotFields("SOW ID")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 2
  End With

  With PTable.PivotFields("Resource Name")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 3
  End With


  With PTable.PivotFields("Deliverable")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 4
  End With

  'Insert Column Fields
  With PTable.PivotFields("Milestone Date")
      .Orientation = xlColumnField
      .Position = 1
  End With

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Milestone 
  Date").AutoSort xlAscending, "Milestone Date"

  'Insert Data Field
    With PTable.PivotFields("Milestone Date")
               .Orientation = xlDataField
               .NumberFormat = "0"
           End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest using Text to Columns instead.  The issue is that vba likes the dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and tries to convert it as such.  so if your strings are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format vba does keeps it as a string.

Comment: Or you can parse the string and make your own date in vba then assign that value and format.  If you give an example of your data, one that does not convert properly, we might be able to help more.

Comment: `.Cells(i, "M").Value2 = Split(.Cells(i, "L"), ",")(1)`

Comment: @Scott Craner I updated to show screenshot of excel, you can see that the two highlighted in yellow are unsuccessful, yet sandwiched between them is a successful result. What would also be good is to not copy to the new column anything that is not a date, you can see some comments have been taken.

Comment: How do you want to handle a string like `31/2/18` (in your first line), since that cannot be translated into a valid date?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah so maybe this is why some of them are not converting? Would the input need to be 31/02/18?

Comment: That is not the issue.  The issue is that there is no such date as `31-Feb-2018`.  Most date functions will convert it to `3-March-2018`.  Is that what you want?  Or do you need to flag it as invalid?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes I guess it would need to be inavlid

Comment: OK, I would do that with Regular Expressions, but I see that you have already marked an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this and it seems to do what you are expecting, it will loop through the cell one character at a time and if it contains anything apart from / or numbers, it will remove them, then it will format the cell as a date:

```
Sub foo()
Dim StartString As String
Dim DateValue As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheets("DataSheet")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row on column L
    .Columns(13).Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'add a new column to the right of column L
    For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop through rows
        If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "L"), ",") Then
            .Cells(i, "M").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "L"), ",")(1) 'split after comma
            StartString = .Cells(i, "L").Value
            DateValue = ""
            For y = 1 To Len(StartString) 'loop to remove unwanted characters
                Select Case Asc(Mid(StartString, y, 1))
                    Case 47 To 57
                        DateValue = DateValue & Mid(StartString, y, 1)
                End Select
            Next y
        .Cells(i, "M").Value = DateValue 'return the date
        .Cells(i, "M").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 'format it correctly
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

If your code does insert the column and populates the cells with all the data after the comma, then you can simply include the following to your code and it should then work for you too:

```
StartString = .Cells(i, "L").Value
DateValue = ""
For y = 1 To Len(StartString) 'loop to remove unwanted characters
    Select Case Asc(Mid(StartString, y, 1))
    Case 47 To 57
        DateValue = DateValue & Mid(StartString, y, 1)
    End Select
Next y
.Cells(i, "M").Value = DateValue 'return the date
.Cells(i, "M").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 'format it correctly
```

Comment: This for some reason does not split the dates in Column L to the new column M? Column M showing only as blank

Comment: @SDROB Sorry updated my answer, it didn't work because I was testing with Columns A and B, but it should now work... As long as the value for newLastRow is correct.

Comment: I still get the same issue? Column M is blank

Comment: The issue I am still having is that the dates are not ordering in the Pivot Table? Is there something else I can do to format so that I can then have the dates sorted as column headers?

Comment: @SDROB so did my answer work for you? What do you mean the dates are not ordering?

Comment: yes the solution worked, thanks! Sorry I did mention in initial question, the dates are needed so that they can be sorted as headers in a pivot in the next stage. But they do not sort correctly at all?

Comment: Do you mean you want them sorted on Column M in ascending order? or... I'm not sure I understand your requirement, can you update your question with a screenshot or something so I can see what's going on?

Comment: updated to include headers that as you can see are not sorted chronologically, and when I analyse the dates using the =ISNUMBER function, not many come back as True

Comment: Can you share the code that places the dates there?

Comment: included the code for the pivot in the original question

Comment: I can see a couple of issues with your code, can I ask what you are trying to do? get the data in ascending order for a pivot table, and then you would want to create a chart? Because if that's the case it would be a lot simpler to create the pivot manually and then refresh the source data programmatically?

Comment: The idea was for the macro to produce the pivot table completely from scratch, and have the dates as column headers. Just these need to be sorted chronologically in ascending order.. Perhaps the second approach would be better in this case?

Comment: I believe so, I've got a similar set-up and it will be a lot fewer lines of code as you won't have to create and delete, just select whatever range you need to update the source data and voila, the pivot would be updated a lot quicker...

Comment: are you able to share how I would change this? And would this fix the issue of the column headers changing? These need to be dynamic as dates will change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161279/discussion-between-sdrob-and-xabier).